# return list pair (print out) from 2 list of same length

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples

I have 2 lists (x and y) and I want to output in x, y (just the print out). May I know how to do it? Do I need a loop to loop through each item in the x and y list?

```
input :
x = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['F', 'G']]
y = [['L', 'M'], ['J', 'K'], ['O', 'P', 'Q']]

output :
x, y format
['A', 'B']   ['L', 'M']
['C', 'D']   ['J', 'K']
['F', 'G']   ['O', 'P', 'Q']
```

The closest I got is as below :

```
for row in x:
    n = []
    for loop in y :
        for x in loop :
            n.append(x) 
        print(' '.join(row).strip().split()) , n

Output :
['A', 'B'] ['L', 'M']
['A', 'B'] ['L', 'M', 'J', 'K']
['A', 'B'] ['L', 'M', 'J', 'K', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
['C', 'D'] ['L', 'M']
['C', 'D'] ['L', 'M', 'J', 'K']
['C', 'D'] ['L', 'M', 'J', 'K', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
['F', 'G'] ['L', 'M']
['F', 'G'] ['L', 'M', 'J', 'K']
['F', 'G'] ['L', 'M', 'J', 'K', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to make tuples of elements of your lists:

```py
list(zip(x, y))
```

Produces:

```
[(['A', 'B'], ['L', 'M']),
 (['C', 'D'], ['J', 'K']),
 (['F', 'G'], ['O', 'P', 'Q'])]
```

The resulting list is, in this example, of length 3. The first element is:

```py
>>> list(zip(x, y))[0]
(['A', 'B'], ['L', 'M'])
```

In order to print the tuples with a space in between:

```py
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    print(f'{a} {b}')
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B'] ['L', 'M']
['C', 'D'] ['J', 'K']
['F', 'G'] ['O', 'P', 'Q']
```

Comment: Hi i dont think i can use list zip, i think i will have hash related issue? for my subsequent scripts

Comment: No hashing necessary for `zip`. The output in my answer is from actually running the proposed code on your exact input example.

Comment: i need to remove " ( [ " and " ]) ", because my subsequent code requires me to do that :(

Comment: so what exactly is the desired output (as a Python object)? The question shows output as text. Not sure what you actually need.

Comment: ['A', 'B']   ['L', 'M']

and 

(['A', 'B'], ['L', 'M'])

it there any difference between these two?

Comment: yes, the second is a Python tuple, as you asked, whereas the first is just a string or printout.

Comment: Hi apologize if my question got mistake, I would like to printout to the exact
That is,
First line : ['A', 'B']   ['L', 'M']
Second line : ['C', 'D']   ['J', 'K']

I'm guessing a loop is necessary, I don't not want a tuple

Comment: Ah. So to just print out the tuples, see updated answer.